# Jest testing, sessionStorage undefined

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I am trying to run my first Jest test but I get this error

```
 FAIL  src\containers\__test__\AppContainer.spec.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    ReferenceError: sessionStorage is not defined
```

I'm not sure if I should be even getting this error as I am not testing sessionStorage, just want to test the root container.

--update--

```
import React from 'react'
import { shallow } from 'enzyme'
import AppContainer from '../AppContainer'

//Tried here also
global.sessionStorage = {
  data: {},
  setItem: (key, value) => {
    this.data[key] = value
  },
  getItem: (key) => this.data[key]
}
describe('AppContainer', () => {
  beforeEach(function () {
    global.sessionStorage = {
      data: {},
      setItem: (key, value) => {
        this.data[key] = value
      },
      getItem: (key) => this.data[key]
    }
  })

  it('should render self and subcomponents', () => {
    const enzymeWrapper = shallow(<AppContainer />)

    expect(enzymeWrapper.find('div').hasClass('grommetux-app')).toBe(true)
  })
})
```

--

```
ReferenceError: sessionStorage is not defined
  at Function.r.get (node_modules\oidc-client\lib\oidc-client.min.js:1:13009)
  at new e (node_modules\oidc-client\lib\oidc-client.min.js:74:15382)
  at new e (node_modules\oidc-client\lib\oidc-client.min.js:74:5255)
  at n (node_modules\redux-oidc\dist\redux-oidc.js:1:1853)
  **at Object.<anonymous> (src\utils\userManager.js:23:127)**
  at Object.<anonymous> (src\containers\AppContainer.js:9:46)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src\containers\__test__\AppContainer.spec.js:3:47)
  at process._tickCallback (internal\process\next_tick.js:103:7)
```

I am "using" sessionStorage via a library, [oidc-clientjs](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js), so I really don't have control over it.

Line 23 that it is the source of the error is

```
import { createUserManager } from 'redux-oidc'
....
const userManager = createUserManager(config) (L23)
```

Comment: Try `window.sessionStorage` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to mock out `redux-oidc`. There are 2 ways to do so.

You need `createUserManager` to behave differently on some tests:

```
//you need to import the module as you need to set the behaviour of 
//createUserManager in every tests
import { createUserManager } from 'redux-oidc' 

//mock the module with an object that just holds createUserManager       
//method as a simple spy, later in your tests you can define what this 
//spy should do
jest.mock('redux-oidc', () => ({createUserManager: jest.fn()}))

it('should render self and subcomponents', () => {
    createUserManager.mockImplementation(() => 'test1234`)//set the mock implementation here
    const enzymeWrapper = shallow(<AppContainer />)
    expect(enzymeWrapper.find('div').hasClass('grommetux-app')).toBe(true)
})
```

`createUserManager` does the same in some tests:

```
//mock the module with an object that just holds createUserManager
//method as a simple function that always returns 'test1234'
jest.mock('redux-oidc', () => ({createUserManager: () => 'test1234'}))

it('should render self and subcomponents', () => {
    const enzymeWrapper = shallow(<AppContainer />)
    expect(enzymeWrapper.find('div').hasClass('grommetux-app')).toBe(true)
})
```

Comment: Could you please post the code that is using `sessionStorage` as well?

Comment: thank you! one final question, issue isn't 100% resolved as I get sessionStorage.getItem is not defined. I have to mock getItem as well? Best way to do it?

Comment: Thats strange cause by mocking `redux-oidc` it should never call any method inside of `redux-oidc`. Or is `sessionStorage.getItem` not called inside `redux-oidc` but in your module? Then you need to follow the approach I showed first.

Comment: yep i am calling session.getItem in my application code. alright thanks

Comment: i'd appreciate an examppe :)) i am very new to this. I tried sessionStorage.getItem.mockImplementation(() => 'test1234') :S

Comment: Ah, you don't have to this. The idea is to replace the `redux-oidc` with something we can control and that never touches `sessionStorage`. That means when you run your tests instead of calling the real implementation of `createUserManager`, your module always calls the the `function ()=> 'test1234'`

Comment: Error: `createUserManager.mockImplementation is not a function`

Answer (score 5):

I am using Create-react-app, so I added this to src/setupTests.js

```
const sessionStorageMock = {
  getItem: jest.fn(),
  setItem: jest.fn(),
  clear: jest.fn()
};
global.sessionStorage = sessionStorageMock;
```